# Does mongodb take advantage of repeated values?

Tags: mongodb

If several documents have internal large fields with a value that occurs more than once in the entire database, will mongodb take advantage of such repeated values by storing just one instance of it and storing the others as references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not for the entire database, since it will be very expensive to decompress.

If you compress the whole database, returning one document would require you to load and uncompress the whole database in memory.

Rather, compression was done per-document using either snappy or zlib (in the WiredTiger storage engine), depending on whether you value speed (snappy) or compression ratio (zlib).